# novice inheritance question

Tags: c#, inheritance

I don't understand why my output is not how I think it should be. I think that it should be Dog barks line break Cat meows. But there is nothing there.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Pets pet1 = new Dog();
      Pets pet2 = new Cat();
      pet1.Say();
      pet2.Say();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  class Pets
  {
   public void Say() { }
  }

  class Dog : Pets
  {
   new public void Say() { Console.WriteLine("Dog barks."); }
  }

  class Cat : Pets 
  {
   new public void Say() { Console.WriteLine("Cat meows."); }
  }
}
```

I have tried to go through the [c# programming guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=VS.80).aspx) but I find it very difficult to understand some of the examples on there. If someone could link to a good "inheritance for dummies" site, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The way you are using Pets is more like an Interface

Comment: I'd de-pluralize Pets to Pet.

Comment: I'd re-pluralize Pets to Petses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make the Say function in your base class virtual and then override this function in your derived classes:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Pets pet1 = new Dog();
      Pets pet2 = new Cat();
      pet1.Say();
      pet2.Say();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  class Pets
  {
   public virtual void Say() {
      Console.WriteLine("Pet makes generic noise");
 }
  }

  class Dog : Pets
  {
    public override void Say() { Console.WriteLine("Dog barks."); }
  }

  class Cat : Pets 
  {
    public override void Say() { Console.WriteLine("Cat meows."); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The `new` modifier as you've written it:

```
class Dog : Pets
{
 new public void Say() { Console.WriteLine("Dog barks."); }
}
```

essentially means that the `Say` method you've defined is only called when that instance is used *as an instance of `Dog`*.

So

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.Say(); // barks (calls Dog.Say)
Pet pet = dog;
pet.Say(); // nothing (calls Pet.Say)
```

That explains why you received the results you *have*; for what you *wanted*, use virtual methods -- [@fletcher's answer explains it well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495372/novice-inheritance-question/3495394#3495394).

Comment: +1 I never even knew you could use the new keyword in this way, wierd.